# Dell 3007WFP Monitor: USB Ports Not Working

Tags: mac, usb, display

I have the monitor described in title and am trying to use the USB ports to plug in a mouse.  I've set up my macbook pro and connected it to the monitor with the DVI cable + Mini DisplayPort to Dual Link DVI adapter.

I can close my laptop and still have my machine's screen display on the monitor.  However, when I plug in any device (mouse, keyboard) into the USBs on the side or under my monitor, I get no response.

Is there a cable that I'm missing that I need to connect from the monitor to the MBP (and then connect all other devices to the USBs on my monitor)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to attach a standard A-B USB cable from one of your computer's USB ports to the back of the monitor.

Here's a picture of that monitor's ports with the USB (B) port circled:

[image: Dell Monitor Ports]

Comment: [Dell 3007WFP User and setup guide](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/dell-3007wfp-hc/manuals)